# Using the Session from a controller

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc

I've add Session to my startup.cs using the app.UseSession middleware, and in the same startup file I'm able to call `context.Session.SetString("key", "value")`, I can even get the value in the same startup.cs file with `context.Session.GetString("key")`, but now, if I wan't to do the same from a controller it doesn't work, if I do:

```
Request.HttpContext.Session.GetString("Key")
```

I get an error telling me Session don't have the GetString method, I already added the Microsoft.AspNet.Session to the using statements.

So, how can I get and set the values to the Session from the controllers?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The session state extension methods are in the `Microsoft.AspNet.Http` namespace: https://github.com/aspnet/HttpAbstractions/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNet.Http.Extensions/SessionCollectionExtensions.cs#L7

Answer (score 1):

If you're in a controller you should actually use the inherited Context property:

```
Context.Session.GetString("key");
```

You can read about it in more detail here: [Using Sessions and HttpContext in ASP.NET 5 and MVC6](http://benjii.me/2015/07/using-sessions-and-httpcontext-in-aspnet5-and-mvc6/)